# How to explicitly convert to fixed-length alphanumeric datatype in 4D

Tags: ssis, type-conversion, visual-studio-2015

I'm building an ETL process in SSIS that extracts data from a [4D](http://www.4d.com/products.html) data source using the manufacturer's own ODBC provider (`4D v16 ODBC Driver`). When I try to extract any type of "string" column, it comes out as a LOB column, meaning that

```
'Row by Row' fetch method is enforced because the table has LOB column(s).
```

My go-to solution would be to `CAST` the offending LOB columns in the source SQL statement to a fixed-length type, but I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax or data type name in 4D. I think the following error message points to a syntax error from 4D:

```
SELECT x, y, CAST(z AS varchar(100)) AS z
FROM someTbl
```

[image: There was an error while trying to get schema information. The table has no columns]

Documentation on the database product is a bit thin, but it would seem that there is no such thing as fixed-length alphanumeric datatypes, but rather just a "string" datatype, which the ODBC provider perhaps translates to LOB.

Is there a way to convert the database column to an alphanumeric datatype that SSIS will see as a fixed-length column?

Comment: Pinged an old coworker about this and his response was "Modern versions of 4D support the SQL 92 standard (mostly) so I would expect there would be some way to cast as something other than a LOB... My guess is that it's related either to the original column definition on the 4D side (which may not be optimal), or some property of the ODBC provider that isn't tweaked right for SSIS"